# Como guardar en una variable el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado c# console & SQL server 2016

Tags: c#, sql, consola

bueno tengo este procedimiento almacenado

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ContarEstudiantes
as
    BEGIN
select sum(CASE WHEN CS.materias is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Estudiantes sin materias reprobadas',
sum(CASE WHEN CS.grupos is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'grupos sin reprobados' 
from cteHCcomplete CS
    END
go
```

y este es mi resultado por ahora, ya que puede cambiar conforme vayan cambiando los registros:

[image: resultado]

y me gustaria ejecutarlo desde un programa en consola en c# y utilizar los datos que arroja como resultados pero no se como, tengo esta idea pero realmente no se como plasmarla en codigo ya que aun sigo aprendiendo por eso pido su apoyo ya sea dandome consejos o algunas pistas para poder realizarlo, mil gracias compañeros.

Comment: Literalmente si buscas en Google tu pregunta, esto aparece en los primeros resultados https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-execute-a-parameterized-stored-procedure-using-entitycommand

Comment: @LuisCazares yo no busco con parametros, como puedes ver en mi codigo solo es una consulta, y ademas quisiera utilizar esos resultados en c#

Comment: Pues no agregues los parámetros

Comment: @LuisCazares y como puedo utilizar o guardar los resultados en una variable?

Comment: Tu SP no devuelve un valor, en realidad no devuelve nada... lo que vos buscas se puede hacer mas simple con una vista.. pero supongamso que tu SP devuelve algo (que no lo hace) entonces, dependiendo lo que retorne, es lo que vas a tener que guardar...

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi d'entrada para los select Vistas, los procedimientos almacenados por inserts,updates,etc.  Para la consulta en c# sin parámetros [Consulta en c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/ad3cfe1e-7ec3-476f-9e0e-91a89f17cd02/hacer-una-consulta-sql-con-c-utilizando-un-data-reader-y-mostrarlo-por-consola?forum=vsexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consumir un procedimiento almacenado en c# es muy simple, y puede tener múltiples beneficios. Empezando por el rendimiento. Y siguiendo porque se pueden aplicar lógicas que no tienen porque estar a nivel de código de servidor. No obstante este es un debate que ya tiene millones de comentarios en la red. Pero un procedimiento, tiene una sintaxis ya analizada y un plan de ejecución asignado, por tanto puede ser mucho más rápido que otras opciones.

Con el escenario que planteas.

```
Create table cteHCcomplete (id int identity(1,1), materias int, grupos int);

insert into cteHCcomplete (materias, grupos)
values 
(null, 0),
(null, 0),
(null, 0),
(1, null),
(1, null);
```

Las filas, y columnas aunque no tengan mucho sentido, plantean resultados a la ejecución del procedure.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ContarEstudiantes
as
    BEGIN
select sum(CASE WHEN CS.materias is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Estudiantes sin materias reprobadas',
sum(CASE WHEN CS.grupos is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'grupos sin reprobados' 
from cteHCcomplete CS
    END
```

El consumo del procedure devuelve resultados.

```
exec dbo.ContarEstudiantes
```

[image: Res1]

En c# preparo un proyecto de consola

[image: Net]

Directamente agrego el código en la clase Program.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inicio programa");
            try
            {
                int est=-1;
                int grp=-1;
                // Create a connection to the server
                string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=HowTo;Integrated Security=true";

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    //Execute Stored Procedure
                    string nameSp = "ContarEstudiantes";

                    Console.WriteLine("Inicio consumo sp");

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(nameSp, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        SqlDataReader sdr = null;
                        try
                        {
                            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {
                                est = sdr.GetInt32(0);
                                grp = sdr.GetInt32(1);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("Leidos datos");
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Estudiantes sin materias {0}, Grupos {1}", est, grp));
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("excepción en la lectura");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("excepción en la lectura");/* Code exeption */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El código es un simple ejemplo, donde se establece una conexión a la base de datos, y se ejecuta el comando, cargando los datos en un simple SqlDataReader, del cual se extraen los valores, después de ejecutar el procedure, mediante los métodos que nos provee. Como yo esperaba unos ints, pues he utilizado GetInt32 y por posición.

[image: Resultado]

Tienes que tener bien claro como se usa la clase SqlClient.

Luego existen múltiples formas para poder extraer los datos, bien sea con un SqlDatareader, o de otras múltiples formas. Pero de todo esto hay un millón de ejemplos en la red.